# How to make user to user relation in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a model user. This user can be of type admin, owner, boss, supervisor.

Now boss can belong to many owners.

How I will make the relation with these users?

The model of both types of users is the same just the type is different.

This is multiauth project. I didn't make separate login. i am just differentiating them on the based of type.

Now problem is owner can has many type of user and other type of users can belongs to many owner. and there database table is same

Comment: show us database schema so we can help you

Comment: that is only one table users . which have columns id,name,email ,type .

Comment: what kind of project you are making please explain in summarised way (i am asking this question because answer can differ from project to project)

Comment: do you mean 1 owner can have many boss ?

Comment: Do you mean     $owner->hasMany(Boss) ?

Comment: yes. not only boss he can also has many supervisor and other type of users

Comment: what is relation ship between other roles like  boss and supervisor  and also admin?

Comment: can 1 user have multiple roles?

Comment: yes user can have multiple role

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228042/discussion-between-dvijparekh-and-bilal-arshad).

Comment: consult senior person if possible you can go on infinity loop  if you have multiple roles per user

Answer (score 1):

You should implement self reference like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function boss()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
After your new edit you can do this by self reference many to many relationship.

Comment: please check comments above and have a look at table schema your answer will give wrong results your answer is partially true and please get an overview of question and then answer it "no offence"   :)

Comment: @dvijparekh the question is obvious, from where you know my answer is wrong and give me down vote? "no offence" too

Comment: i do have answer but even it is partial i am stucked on one thing and solution is not as simple as you think 
i am looking for one solution where i am stuck i will post solution soon and tag you in comment

Comment: yes it is necesarry brother this will remind  you that you have to anwser patiently because your wrong answer will frustate other people

Comment: hey I have updated the question can you look at it?

Comment: @AbolfazlMohajeri I guess this will be a many to many relation among users so just add  pivot table which will have user_id,child_id both of these keys will point to user table and each user will have single type and. Hope this solves the issue. Rest leave the down voters they can't post better solution  so they criticize they need to realize  that OP wan not clear and incomplete details but they expect answer to be perfect. Cheers